# How can I 301 redirect specific subdomain URLs using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect particular URLs on a subdomain to *completely different* URLs on a different subdomain. For example:

```
http://foo.example.com/this-is-my-page
```

Needs to `301` to:

```
http://bar.example.com/this-is-really-my-page
```

I’ve tried setting up a simple `Redirect 301` in `.htaccess` but it doesn't seem to work.  For example:

```
Redirect 301 http://foo.example.com/this-is-my-page http://bar.example.com/this-is-really-my-page
```

Comment: probably needs to be somewhere else in the apache config.  what operating system are you on?

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://newsub.domain.com/ [L,R]
```

it works on my side

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
# first re-write all foo.example.com requests to bar.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://bar.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# now re-write each individual URL
RewriteRule ^this-is-mypage /this-is-really-my-page [NC,L,R=301]
```