# How to 301 redirect 3 same WordPress sites with different subdomains

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

So this is a tricky one. WooCommerce (at time of writing) does not allow multiple currencies in one instance of WordPress so what we have had to do is triplicate the site [until they bring out this feature](http://ideas.woothemes.com/forums/133476-woocommerce/suggestions/2502035-woocommerce-multi-site-shopping-cart-feature)

So this is our scenario and the 301 we need to get right. The old site was at..

example.co.za and the shop was at example.co.za/shop

We then registered a .com and triplicated the site to offer prices in US$ and South African Rand (ZAR) as we would be targeting overseas buyers.

Our set up now looks like this...

- The original site has been moved to example.com and the shop has been removed from this domain so that only the blog sits on this domain
- We then set up shop.example.com and duplicated the site on this subdomain. Here we removed the blog and only left the shop. We also converted all prices on this site to US$
- We then also set up shop.example.co.za and did the same as above. Removed the blog and left only the shop in ZAR.

We now need to do a 301 redirect but a simple 301 redirect does not just redirect to a subdomain (why I don't know)

Redirect 301 /shop/fabric-products/cotton/ http://shop.example.co/fabric-products/cotton/

I had a look [at this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845098/how-can-i-301-redirect-specific-subdomain-urls-using-htaccess#) but because of the nature of this situation, it is going to be a little more complex than just rewriting all the subdomains and from one to another.

What I am thinking is that is that there must be some conditions or exclusions one can add so that you redirect the bulk of the URL's but for the shop element, you would write another condition?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about using the RedirectMatch directive:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /shop/(.*) http://shop.example.com/$1
```

For more information look at: http://alvinalexander.com/web/apache-redirectmatch-examples-wildcard-301

Comment: Thanks Obmerk will look into this